# How to query a list of rows based with array?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-adapter, listadapter

Why can't I just query my users in such a way so as to return a list of pre-specified users by populating an array with the users I want to manually feature?

```
String[] topUsers = {"pYYMsL9RWW", "XdvlyOgS3n", "J5YDxiXc3U"};

final ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", topUsers);
```

Comment: Because you're asking for a generic many-to-many match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

query.whereContainsAll("objectId", topUsers);

Documentation: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-queries-on-array-values

Update:

Should use, query.whereContainedIn("objectId", topUsers);

Comment: I get a "wrong 2nd argument type" problem here. ``Found java.lang.String[], required: java.util.Collection<?>``

Comment: Sorry, you should use `whereContainedIn("objectId", topUsers)`